# JSON Request doesn't complete

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am new to JavaScript and is making my first attempt at a JSON `XMLHttpRequest`.

According to the book, Head First: HTML5 Programming, the code needs to look like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var url = "<url here>";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onload = function() {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            updateSales(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}

function updateSales(responseText) {
    var salesDiv = document.getElementById("sales");
    salesDiv.innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

I put the URL for my own server where the JSON file is. The JSON file itself looks like this:

```
[{"name":"ARTESIA","time":1308774240669,"sales":8},
{"name":"LOS ANGELES","time":1308774240669,"sales":2},
{"name":"PASADENA","time":1308774240669,"sales":8},
{"name":"STOCKTON","time":1308774240669,"sales":2},
{"name":"FRESNO","time":1308774240669,"sales":2},
{"name":"SPRING VA LLEY","time":1308774240669,"sales":9},
{"name":"ELVERTA","time":1308774240669,"sales":5},
{"name":"SACRAMENTO","time":1308774240669,"sales":7},
{"name":"SAN MATEO","time":1308774240669,"sales":1}]
```

I don't know what I am missing here as I even tried to do copy-paste.

EDIT:

Here is the page that loads the script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Mighty Gumball (JSON)</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="mightygumball.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mightygumball.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Mighty Gumball Sales</h1>
        <div id="sales">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you've got?

Comment: @AJeneral I get no errors. It just won't load on my HTML page. I probably should include that as well. Give me a second.

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/syvrx6xo/

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It doesn't show the JSON data on the page though.

Comment: Probably CORS error?

Comment: @cevek Can you elaborate? I am new to JavaScript so I don't know what a CORS error is :c

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
This happens when domain where your script is running don't correspond to domain which return json

Comment: @cevek ooooh...yeah I have to look into JSONP apparently. Thanks!